# PasteSpecial Method Odd Error

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have gone through the similar questions and have not found anything with this specific error.

I am trying to make a macro that goes through a large number of CSV files, pulls the necessary information I need, copies and pastes that data to a new Workbook, and then closes the CSV file and goes to the next one.

When I test my code and have it run Step by Step (using F8) it functions fine and there are no error.  However, whenever I try and just have the code run (like pressing F5) I get the error "PasteSpecial Method of Class Range" failed.  When I press debug this line of the code is highlighted:
 copyRange.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

I added a small time delay of 0.5s before this line and it actually was able to go further through the files before failing.

Is it something with the Range.Offset method? Should I explicitly define a different copy range?

Code I have follows below:

```
Public Sub OpenTXT_CopyNewWBK(inPath As String)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile, queue As Collection
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = True
    Dim dataRange As Range, dateRange As Range, copyRange As Range
    Dim lastCell, lastRow As String
    Dim newBook, wbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim csvStart As Long
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
    With newBook
        .SaveAs Filename:="BETA RAY " & Format(Now, "ddmmyyhhmmss")
    End With
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder(inPath) 'obviously replace
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            Set wbk = app.Workbooks.Add(oFile.Path)
            lastCell = wbk.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address
            If Len(lastCell) = 6 Then
                lastRow = Mid(lastCell, 4, 3)
            ElseIf Len(lastCell) = 5 Then
                lastRow = Mid(lastCell, 4, 2)
            ElseIf Len(lastCell) = 4 Then
                lastRow = Mid(lastCell, 4, 1)
            End If
            Set dateRange = wbk.Sheets(1).Range("A2", lastCell)
                dateRange.Select
            Set dataRange = wbk.Sheets(1).Range("AA2", "AM" & lastRow)
                dataRange.Select
            wbk.Application.CutCopyMode = True
            Set copyRange = Workbooks(newBook.name).Sheets(1).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)
            If Not copyRange = "" Then
                Set copyRange = copyRange.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            dateRange.Copy
            copyRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            wbk.Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wbk.Application.CutCopyMode = True
            Application.Wait (Now + 500 * 0.00000001)
            dataRange.Copy
            copyRange.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            wbk.Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next oFile
    Loop
    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing
    Range("B:B").Delete
    Range("G:G").Delete
    Range("L:L").Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am sure there are much better ways to do a lot of the things I have going on there.  I really just use VBA to make my life easier at work so a lot of the code I use is copy, pasted, and modified to fit my needs.  I couldn't figure out how to make this method work `wbk2.sht2.Range("A1:A5") = wbk1.sht1.Range("B1:B5")` everything I have read says this should be a much better method.  Also, the portions of code that read `dataRange.Select` and `dateRange.Select` are just there for debugging purposes.

Comment: Where are you running this code?  Word?  Access?  VBScript?  VB.Net?  The fact that you are having to create two new Excel application objects (`app` and `objExcel`) makes me think it isn't Excel.  Oops, no, perhaps it is Excel - you use a `Workbooks` object without referring to either `app` or `objExcel`.  So `daterange` and `datarange` are in the `app` instance of Excel, and `copyRange` is in the native instance.  This is confusing.  Why do you need so many instances?

Comment: There may be an extra one that I forgot to delete as I tried new methods of opening the Excel workbooks.  I am trying to read data from the CSV files in an instance of excel that is in the background ie not visible

Comment: Multiple instances of Excel will possibly (probably?) be the cause of not being able to just assign values from one location to the other, and possibly of your issues with copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
wbk2.sht2.Range("A1:A5").value = wbk1.sht1.Range("B1:B5").value
```

Comment: I stated I had tried to get that method to work but was running into issues with the fact that my ranges of data I am trying to pull are not all the same size and vary quite significantly.

Comment: Essentially you need the range you are copying to to be the same size as the range you are copying. You could achieve this using something like this ....   `Dim copyWbk As Workbook  
    Set copyWbk = Workbooks(newBook.Name).Sheets(1)  
    copyWbk.Range(copyRange, copyRange.Offset(dataRange.Rows.Count - 1, dataRange.Columns.Count - 1)).Values = dataRange.value`

Comment: I just spotted a few mistakes in there. I meant to put this...
   
`Dim copySht As Worksheet
 
Set copySht = Workbooks(newBook.Name).Sheets(1)  

copySht.Range(copyRange, copyRange.Offset(dataRange.Rows.Count - 1, dataRange.Columns.Count - 1)).Values = dataRange.value`